# Python Big Data Matrix manipulation

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I think I have a big data (N = 1e6 and dimension = 3 ) scenario. I require to do some matrix manipulation such as einsum, matrix inversion etc several times in my code. To give an idea I want to do something like below.

```
import numpy.random as rd

ndata, kdata = 1e6, 1e5

x = rd.normal(0,1,(ndata, kdata,3,3))

y = rd.normal(0,1,(ndata, kdata,3,3))
```

For small ndata, kdata following would be efficient and convenient approach,

```
xy =  einsum('pqrs, pqsu -> pqru', x, y )
```

Since I have large ndata and kdata above approach becomes a memory bound problem so next bet would be the dot product with nested for loop over ndata and kdata as follows:

```
xyloop1 = np.empty((ndata, kdata, 3, 3))

for j in xrange(ndata):

    for k in xrange(kdata):

        xyloop1[j,k] =  np.dot(x[j,k], y[j,k] )
```

Given what I am taught for loops are nasty in python. Also, I want to use benefits of numpy so thought block matrix approach would be preferable something like following:

```
nstep = 200
ndiv  = ndata/nstep   

kstep = 200
kdiv  = kdata/kstep   

xyloop2 = np.empty((ndata, kdata, 3, 3))

for j in xrange(ndiv):

    ji, jf = j*nstep, (j+1)*nstep     

    for k in xrange(kdiv):

        ki, kf = k*kstep, (k+1)*kstep     

        xyloop2[ji:jf,ki:kf] =  einsum('pqrs, pqsu -> pqru', x[ji:jf,ki:kf], y[ji:jf,ki:kf] )
```

Also, I need these xy or xyloop1 or xyloop2 for my further calculation. So I have to write and read it after every computation. Given the bandwidth of system I/O do you reckon best approach would be approach 3 as it means less I/O and also small number of iterations in compare to approach 2? If you have any other idea or need more info please let me know.

I am new to the stack so please be gentle with me :). Any help will be highly appreciated. BTW I am trying to solve a mixture modelling problem for a big data. Thanks!

Comment: It's a very good question, but in the end, you're the only one who can answer it correctly. :)  Profile things and see which is fastest for your particular problem. Both are good approaches.  Exactly which approach will be fastest is going to depend heavily on the size of your input data and exactly what you're doing.  You might also consider altering your first version to vectorize the calculation along one axis and loop over the other.  Vectorization is a trade-off between memory usage and speed.  It's often best to remove only one part of a nested loop if memory usage is an issue.

Comment: Thanks @JoeKington for comment. For a clarity purpose I only mentioned the dot product in the inner loop. In such case like u said vectorizing the inner loop is definitely the way to go. However, in reality I am doing several matrix algebra including inverse, transpose, a couple of more time dot products etc. So I guess vectorizing or using list comprehension for the inner loop is not a good idea. Regarding, the first part of your comment I will do the profiling and post it. I like to add that using **cvxopt** LAPACK and BLAS package and approach 2 equals the speed of approach 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I agree with the comment that the only way to know for sure is to profile things for yourself, there are a few guiding principles that can help you write efficient `numpy` code on the first try.  Here are a few suggestions for your problem:

- The overhead for creating a new numpy array is of order 1000 times the cost of an add/multiply, so approach 2 should be inefficient since each call to `np.dot` creates an array but only performs 27 add-multiplies.
- If you are going to have a slow for-loop in python, do it over the left most axis if possible (for C-ordered arrays).
- It is very hard to write very general N-dimensional code efficiently, so my guess is that as series of simpler `numpy` calls will be more efficient than `np.einsum`.  Try `C = np.sum(A[...,:,None] * B[...,:,:], axis=-2)` (this is quite speculative though).

So I would try something like the following:

```
xyloop2 = np.empty((ndata, kdata, 3, 3))

for i in xrange(ndata):
    xyloop2[i] = np.sum(x[i,:,:,:,None] * y[i,:,None,:,:], axis=-2)
```

Similar to approach 2, but much simpler (and more efficient) for-loop. Also swapped out the matrix multiply for something I think might be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, sometime einsum is efficient. Examples with p,q,r,s to be 100, 50, 3, 3

Example I:

```
%timeit tt=np.einsum('pqrs, pqsu->pqru',x,y)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.45 ms per loop

%timeit zz= np.sum(x[:,:,:,None,:]*y[:,:,:,None],axis=-2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 153 µs per loop
```

Example II:

```
%timeit zz= np.sum(x[:,:,:,None,:]*y[:,:,:,None,None],axis=-2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 274 µs per loop

%timeit tt=np.einsum('pqrs, pqs->pqr',x,y)
10000 loops, best of 3: 151 µs per loop

np.allclose(zz,tt)
True
```